# The existence of a contradiction between the two cases related to division

Tags: polynomials, divisibility

I came across the following problem:

We know that by comparing coefficients.

**Case A**: It is impossible for a non-zero polynomial $p(y)+q(z)+ax+b=F(x,\,y,\,z)$ to be divided by the polynomial $x^2+1$ because the degree of $F$ (in $x$) is $1$. See: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/384455/what-are-conditions-such-that-the-polynomial-x21-divides-pyqzaxb-fx

Here $p$ and $q$ are also polynomials and $a$, $b$ are real numbers.

Now passing to the **values** of these polynomials and consider the logical case:

**Case B**: There exist values of $x,y,z,a,b,c$ such that $x^2+1$ divides $p(y)+q(z)+ax+b=F(x,\,y,\,z)$

I am asking about the existence of a contradiction between the two cases.

Comment: Do you believe that $\,f(x)\nmid g(x)\Rightarrow f(a)\nmid g(a)?\,$ There are simple  counterexamples

Comment: @BillDubuque: Can we find some conditions on that polynomial to guarantee that the property holds and a contradiction can be made.

Comment: @Safwane Not really.  It’s obvious that there is always a choice of $b$ that makes $F(x,y,z)$ equal to any value you want, so it can always be made divisible by $x^2+1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no contradiction here. If Case A holds then Case B also holds. This is better illustrated by an example: Let $F(x,y,z)=x+1$,
which cannot be devided by $x^2+1$. However, you can see that $(1)^2+1=2$ divides $F(1,y,z)=2$.

Comment: Can we find some conditions on that polynomial to guarantee that the property holds and a contradiction can be made.